# Displaying json arrays with jQuery .each

Tags: jquery, json, each

I have a json file that I want to pull data from. When the json file is not in an array than everything works just fine. I guess the problem is that I do not know how to select the correct data in my .each function. Here is the example json file:

```
{
   "chapter1": [
      {
         "title":"This is the title",
         "chapter":"1",
         "verse":"1",
         "text":"text goes here"
      },
      {
         "verse":"4",
         "text":"text goes here"
      },
      {
         "verse":"6",
         "text":"text goes here"
      }
   ],

   "chapter2": [
      {
         "title":"This is the title",
         "chapter":"2",
         "verse":"1",
         "text":"text goes here"
      },
      {
         "verse":"4",
         "text":"text goes here"
      },
      {
         "verse":"6",
         "text":"text goes here"
      }
   ]
}
```

Here is my loop to display the data:

```
$.getJSON(passages, function(data) {
    $.each(data, function() {
        $('#chapter1 h2').append(this.title);
        $('#chapter1 h3').append(this.chapter);
        $('#verses').append('<li><p>' + this.verse + this.text + '</p></li>');    
    });
});
```

When I remove the "chapter2" data from the json file, than everything works just fine. I would like to display the "chapter1" contents and the "chapter2" contents.

Comment: What are you using to create the JSON, because it seems like there is some inconsistency there

Comment: It's just a .json file I plugged some data into.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, it's creating an array around members of each element.  Assuming this is consistent, you can access `title` and `chapter` like so:

```
$("#chapter1 h2").append(this[0].title);
$("#chapter1 h3").append(this[0].chapter);
```

EDIT:  If you are creating the JSON yourself you should probably change its format to something like this:

```
"chapter": {
   "title": "the title",
   "chapter": "the chapter",
   "verses": [
      {"verse": "1", "text": "text 1"},
      {"verse": "4", "text": "text 2"}
   ]
}
```

This will work with the `$.each` in your question

Comment: So I reformatted the json data like you suggested and now nothing is showing up. Am I suppose to change something in my $.each statement?

Comment: @user715564 what do you mean "nothing is showing up?"  Do you get an error?

Comment: Haha that's what I mean. Nothing is showing up in the specified divs in the $.each statement. The data is not being displayed. I don't see any errors in the console. Either way, your first suggestion worked. I can go ahead and go that route for now and work on formatting later. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

the json is malformed, json for each chapter should look something like this:

```
    "chapter1": {
       "title":"this is the title",
       "chapter":"1",
       "verses":[
          {
             "verse":"1",
             "text":"some text"
          },
          {
             "verse":"2",
             "text":"some other text"
          },
      ]
   }
```

EDIT:
After you change your JSON, you code should look somthing like this:

```
$.getJSON(passages, function(data) {
    $.each(data, function() {
        $('#chapter1 h2').append(this.title);
        $('#chapter1 h3').append(this.chapter);
        $.each(this.verses,function(){
           $('#verses').append('<li><p>' + this.verse + this.text + '</p></li>');     
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: That still doesn't work with my $.each statement though? the data isn't displayed and there are no errors in the console

Comment: that is because you have to change your code so that it also iterates each chapter verse, inside the each for the chapters, you need another each for the verses